# Azure Workbook - Add a link to another grid

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I've got an azure workbook with an overview grid with all the batches(see picture) and a grid for each of the batchjobs with more detailed information(see picture).
[Overview grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoTxN.png)
[Detailed grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lahOd.png)

In the overview grid, I would like to click on the batch name in each row and get transported to each of the batchjobs detailed grid.
For example if I click on accounts in the overview table, I would like to be transported to the Accounts Batchjobs grid.
Is there a way to do it?

I know you can create a links/tabs list, but I would like to use the overview grid that I've got and add the link there.

Answer (score 0):

You can.  one way is to have the first grid "export" the selected row + column values as parameters, and then have the "downstream" grid reference those parameters to update the query to show just the specific items, item/detail style.

see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-configurations#interactivity